# What do we call "adjacent sequences/series" in English?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my language, two sequences are adjacent if the first is increasing, the second is decreasing, and their difference converges to 0. I couldn't find anything online about it; what's the name for that concept in English?

Also, what are the properties of adjecent sequences, what importance does it have to label them as such?

I have a problem where $u_n = \sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k^2}$, and $v_n = u_n + 1/n$

I want to prove that these series are adjacent, but I don't see how either of them could be decreasing; with every greater n, we're adding a positive number, no? Where am I going wrong, conceptually and mathematically? Thanks.

Comment: $u_n$ is increasing.  It's the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry, I got a little confused. In that case, how could $v_n$ be decreasing? Thanks.

Comment: Just compute $v_{n+1}-v_n$.  You'll see it's negative.